# function's symmetry

Tags: functions, symmetry

I have the function $f(x)=e^x+e^{2-x},x\in\mathbb{R}$ and I want to prove that $f$'s graph has symmetry with respect to $x=1$. Any ideas? 
Can I prove that the function $f(x-1)$ is odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that $f(1-x)=f(1+x)$ (which is the same as $x \mapsto f(1-x)$ is even)

Here you have:
$$f(1-x)=e^{1-x}+e^{2-(1-x)}=e^{1-x}+e^{1+x}$$
$$f(1+x)= e^{1+x}+e^{2-(1+x)}=e^{1+x}+e^{1-x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let consider the horizontal translation $X+1=x$

- $f(x)=e^x+e^{2-x}\to f(X)=e^{1+X}+e^{1-X}$

and

- $f(X)=f(-X)$